# LearnStreet Ruby for Beginners Lesson 9.12

Tags: ruby

Hi i'm stuck on defining instance methods.  The tutorial asks:

Define a method called balance in the class BankAccount which returns the balance.

The code has:

```
class BankAccount
      def initialize(balance)
          @balance = balance
      end
    # your code here
end
```

I'm really confused as to what the question is asking.  Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial is asking you to define a "`getter`" for the `BankAccount` class:

```
class BankAccount
      def initialize(balance)
          @balance = balance
      end
      def balance
         @balance  # remember that the result of last sentence gets returned in ruby  
      end
end
```

Then, you can do

```
bankAccount = BankAccount.new 22 # the value 22 is the balance that gets passed to initialize
bankAccount.balance # 22
```

Now, if what the tutorial is asking is a class method (to me it's not really clear), you should do:

```
      def self.balance  # self is here so you define the method in the class
         @balance
      end
```

Then you can do `BankAccount.balance`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's take the example code:

```
class BankAccount
      def initialize(balance)
          @balance = balance
      end
    # your code here
end
```

in here you are defining a `BankAccount` class which define the `BankAccount#initialize` method (also called constructor) that will be automatically called on the creation of a `BankAccount` object via `BankAccount::new`:

```
BankAccount.new( 123 )
```

In the above example `@balance` will be set to `123`. `@balance` is an instance variable (notice the `@` before the name) which means that you can access it *per-object* within any method you define.

To return that variable, as the exercise ask, you can use the keyword `return` within the `BankAccount#balance` method as follows:

```
def balance
    return @balance
end
```

The Ruby syntax also allows you to omit `return` (as it is intended to always return the last evaluated expression from a method) leading to a more concise syntax:

```
def balance
    @balance
end
```

For this kind of *getter-methods* (= methods that return an instance variable) there is an easily utility: `attr_reader` that you can use as follows:

```
class BankAccount

    attr_reader :balance

    def initialize(balance)
        @balance = balance
    end

end
```

But don't worry, you'll probably learn about the above very soon.
Happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
class BankAccount

    attr_reader :balance

    def initialize(balance)
        @balance = balance
    end

end
```

add attr_reader :balance